# C char * assigning

Tags: c, pointers

I'm starting to learn C and I want to create a string of characters. The example I'm using does it this way:

```
char *c = malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); // 2

*c = 'A';
*c++ = 'B';

printf('%s', c); //doesn't print anything?
```

So my question is, how do I print the string AB?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", c); `

Comment: note that `*c++='B';`means `*c=B,c++;`

Comment: when you compile, check warnings: your `'%s'` given one for sure! Beware of the fact that malloc won't clean memory, so the string terminator may be missing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing this: `*c++ = 'B';` you incremented the pointer. That's why `printf` won't print anything.

Strings in C and C++ are required to end in a zero byte (`\x00`). `printf` rely on this to work correctly. The correct way to do it (regarding your code) would be:

```
char *c = malloc(3 * sizeof(char)); // 2

*c = 'A';
*(c+1) = 'B';
*(c+2) = 0

printf("%s", c);
```

This is by no means effective. Normally we declare literal strings like this:

```
char *c = "ab";
```

If you're trying to get a good feeling of how pointers works. Then your approach is a good exercise. Just understand that the unary `++` operator increment the variable to which is applied, hence, `c` pointer won't point to the beginning of the string no more after you apply it. That's why `*(c+1)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you fixed! Grabbing a bite and then give you correct answer (Have to wait for 10 min;))

Comment: @MouNtant I added just a bit more of explanation just to make it clearer for you :) Keep working!! :)

Comment: Thanks! I know it is inefficient but the example was for learning ;) the c+1 is great tip!

Comment: @MouNtant: Just to note, in this context you will more commonly see `c[1]` instead of `*(c+1)`, even though they are functionally identical.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need a valid C-string (which has a null-terminating character). So add

   `*c = '\0'; // at the end`
2. You are overwriting `'A'` with `'B'`. If you want the string `"AB"`, then do:

   `*c++ = 'A';`
   `*c++ = 'B';`
3. You've incremented `c`, so it no longer points to the beginning of the string. Save a pointer to the very start:

   `char* str = c;`
   `// Now modify c`
   `printf("%s", str);`
4. You were passing `'%s'` to `printf`, which is wrong. You need to pass a *string* (`"%s"`). See #3.
5. As @sharth pointed out (which I missed), you're also only allocating space for 2 `char`s, but if you want the string `"AB"` you need space for 3 `char`s (one for `'A'`, one for `'B'`, and one for `'\0'`).

Putting it all together, it looks like:

```
char* c = malloc(3); // sizeof(char) is always 1
char* str = c; // Save a pointer to the start of the string

*c++ = 'A';
*c++ = 'B';
*c = '\0';

printf("%s", str);

free(str); // Don't forget to free what you malloc
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to remember something very important when using string in C, they are terminated by the NULL character '\0', so always be sure to make room for it when creating a string dynamically.

```
char *c = malloc(3 * sizeof(*c)); // You want to create the string AB so make room for 3
c[0] = 'A';
c[1] = 'B';
c[2] = '\0'; // Terminate the string with the \0 character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *c = malloc(3);
strcpy(c, "AB");
printf("%s", c);
```

Comment: A bit terse, but all there - could use explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix 4 issues:

1. Reserve 3 spaces (not 2) to hold 2 chars.
2. Add `\0` to the last to terminate the `char *`.
3. As @PauloBu says, `*c++ = 'B'` only increments the pointer not the address you want to set, you should use `*(c+1)` instead.
4. Use `"%s"` to print `char *` instead of `'%s'`.

In all, your code needs to change to

```
char *c = (char *) malloc(3 * sizeof(char)); // 3

*c = 'A';
*(c+1) = 'B';
*(c+2) = '\0';

printf("%s", c);
```

Comment: #1 is wrong.  In C, the cast is _not_ required.  It is not an error to include it though.  Suspect most prefer the cast be omitted.

Comment: @chux Yes, you're right. I write this as I just test it under C++. Fixed the answer. Thanks.